# "Unspecified error" when calling getElementsByClassName

Tags: html, powershell, com, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to build a script on PowerShell that would go to a Google Group page and then accept all posts from spam (believe me, it's for the greater good). This is what I've got so far:

```
$URI = "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!pendingmsg/v17ifes"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate($URI)
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }

(($ie.document.getElementsByClassName("F0XO1GC-F-a"))[0]).click()
```

The last line should select one element from the page (its classname is unique) and then just click it. When I test the code `console.log((document.getElementsByClassName("F0XO1GC-F-a")[0]).click())` in IE, it works perfectly as it should. But when I execute the code it catches the following exception:

```
Erro não especificado. (Unspecified error)
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ (($ie.document.getElementsByClassName("F0XO1GC-F-a"))[0]).click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I've tried a few alternatives, but I noticed that even `$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName` returns the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which operating system are you running this from? I have had issues previously when trying to use the `InternetExplorer.Application` object in a similar way whilst running on Windows Server. This was because of the IE security policies which were in place by default. Could this be affecting you?

Comment: I've tried both W7 and 10. Which security settings did you change. I've tried lowering them all and it didn't make any change.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed I missed a question mark... Which security settings did you change?